# setContentPane() works but getContentPane().add() doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, frame, layout-manager, contentpane

This is my code. When I `setContentPane(panel)` it works, but when I `getContentPane().add(panel)` it doesn't work.

Why doesn't the second method work? (It doesn't show me anything)

```
public MyFrame() {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JMenuBar mnuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu mnu1 = new JMenu("aaa");
    mnu1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);

    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Insert Places", KeyEvent.VK_T);
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            count = 0;
            jt = new ArrayList[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                jt[i] = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLocation(0, 0);
            panel.setSize(d.width, d.height);
            panel.setLayout(null);


            JButton add = new JButton("lllll");
            add.setSize(120, 80);
            add.setLocation(250, 100);

            add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                        JTextField jt1 = new JTextField(20);
                        jt1.setSize(150, 30);
                        jt1.setLocation(450 + i * 200, 80 + count * 50);
                        jt1.setVisible(true);
                        jt[i].add(jt1);
                        panel.add(jt1);
                    }
                    count++;

                    frame.repaint();

                }
            });
            panel.add(add);

            JButton confirm = new JButton("ccc");
            confirm.setSize(120, 80);
            confirm.setLocation(250, 200);

            confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    count = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < jt[0].size(); j++) {
                        try {

                            connect.insertPlace(Integer.parseInt(jt[0]
                                .get(j).getText()), jt[1].get(j).getText(),
                                Integer.parseInt(jt[2].get(j).getText()),
                                Integer.parseInt(jt[3].get(j).getText()));
                            count++;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "ERROR",
                                0, null);
                        }
                    }

                    JLabel countL = new JLabel("" + count
                        + "    ??? ??? ??     ");
                    countL.setSize(100, 100);
                    countL.setLocation(250, 350 + jt.length * 10);
                    panel.add(countL);
                    frame.repaint();

                }
            });
            panel.add(confirm);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        }
    });
    mnu1.add(menuItem);
    mnuBar.add(mnu1);
    frame.setJMenuBar(mnuBar);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Layout` of the existing contentpane is such, that your panel isn't sized correctly and doesn't display. Compare the layout of the existing contentpane, the `JFrame` and your `JPanel` and notice the differences.

Comment: I wanna put my buttons arbitrary in my panel. what layout should I use?

Comment: *"I wanna put my buttons arbitrary in my panel"*  Use an `ArbitraryLayout`.  OK no, just kidding.  But **every** layout has some form of logic behind it, and that logic should be expressed in one of 1) A J2SE layout manager.  2) A custom layout manager, or 3) A combination of layout managers. -- So ha!  My `ArbitraryLayout` isn't sounding quite as silly now, is it?

Comment: Indeed, you should decide how you want to layout your buttons and panels, then use a combination of different layout managers to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [the tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html):

> Specify the component's location (for example, `BorderLayout.LINE_END`) as one of the arguments to the `add` method. If this component is missing from a container controlled by a `BorderLayout` object, make sure that the component's location was specified and no another component was placed in the same location.

From what I can see, you have

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

But then, you don't specify its location.

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

Try, instead,

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

---

Also, I'm not sure if the order of the following operations is relevant

```
panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLocation(0, 0);
panel.setSize(d.width, d.height);
panel.setLayout(null);
```

But you may set the layout directly on the constructor.

```
panel = new JPanel(null);
```

And, since your panel is going to be inserted in a container controlled by a layout manager, you shouldn't need to specify its location. As to its dimensions, you may specify its preferred size instead, although this isn't deemed as a good practice by some.

```
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width, d.height));
```